# wrong content loaded due to browser cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, browser-cache

I used Ruby on Rails for my website. In one web page, it will load a poll information based on the poll id, which set in url like "http://mywebsite/polls/1". The poll information includes the poll owner name, the poll title, the item pictures in the poll and the people's name who voted on the poll.

I found sometimes it loaded wrong information. That is, it loaded the wrong poll owner name, poll title and voted people from the other poll while the item pictures are correct.I checked the back end and found there was nothing wrong in rails controller. All the variables got the right values. But the chrome browser told me the view is wrong.

If I cleared all the cache and reload the page then it would work normally.Anyone knows why does it happen and what should I do? Thanks

The relavant action codes：

```
def show
  @poll=Poll.where("is_deleted = false AND id = #{params[:id]}")[0]
  @items=@poll.items.where("is_deleted = false")
  @voted_user_ids = @poll.audiences.where('has_voted != 0').map(&:user_id).uniq
  @voted_users = User.where('id IN (?)',@voted_user_ids)
  @voted_user_names = @voted_users.map(&:user_name)
  if current_user.nil?
    @poll_vote_url = "/voted_choice"
  else 
    @current_user_name = current_user.user_name
    @poll_vote_url = "/audiences/"+@poll.id.to_s
    @if_current_user_voted = @voted_users.include?(current_user)
    @is_poll_owner = (current_user == @poll.user)
    check_item_id_in_cookies
  end
end 

def check_item_id_in_cookies
  if !cookies.signed[:item_id].nil?
    item = Item.find(cookies.signed[:item_id].to_i)
    #create audience if the voter is not the poll owner
    if current_user == item.poll.user
      flash.now[:alert] = "You can't vote on your own poll."  
      cookies.signed[:item_id] = nil
    else
      create_audience cookies.signed[:item_id]
    end
  end
end

def create_audience item_id
  @item_id = item_id.to_i
  @item = Item.find(@item_id)
  @poll = @item.poll 
  @voted_user_ids = @poll.audiences.where('has_voted != 0').map(&:user_id).uniq
  if @voted_user_ids.include?(current_user.id)
    flash.now[:alert]="You already voted."
  else
    audience = @item.poll.audiences.find{|audience| audience.user_id == current_user.id} || Audience.create(:poll_id => @poll.id,:user_id => current_user.id)
    #update audience
    audience.is_following = true
    audience.has_voted = @item.id
    audience.save
    cookies.signed[:item_id]=nil
    flash[:alert]="Thank you for your vote"
    redirect_to "/polls/#{@poll.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you're caching the action by mistake? Can you check that, and if not, show the relevant action code?

Comment: @AmirF I added the relavant action codes

Answer (score 0):

Please monitor the network while loading and reloading the page. Especially to request to request to `http://mywebsite/polls/1`. Check the response headers as well. Even if you don't do on application side the web server or a proxy server may be modifying the request.

You can find help on who to use the network panel of chrome [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network).